# Enabled system app's launcher activity. still app icon is not displayed after OS upgrade

Tags: android-activity, android-launcher, appicon, app-launcher, application-icon

Initial version of my application had no launcher activity, Enabled it for the next release, but i am not seeing app icon after OS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is one of the few things that you cannot change via an "upgrade". You need to tell your users to uninstall and reinstall your app.